# OPC UA vs Socketio

Tags: http, websocket, tcp, socket.io, opc-ua

What is the difference between socketio and OPC UA and when would I choose which protocol?

Are socketio and OPC UA the same type of protocol and alternatives of each other or do they fit into different catergories.

Are there any alternatives to these protocols?

Comment: *"Are there any alternatives to these protocols?"* - This question is too broad. If you are looking for alternatives then please specify a clear use case where the protocols you have available don't fit your specific use case and also explain why they are not a fit. If you don't even have an idea what the available protocols are doing as seem to be the case here, then it makes no sense to ask for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Both are quite different even if they share some features.
To be basic, those 2 are used in different roles.

- Socket.IO = real-time web communication
- OPC UA = industrial automation communication

Yes there is quite a lot of alternatives to those 2 protocols:

- MQTT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT)
- Web Socket (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
- XMPP / Jabber (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)
- AQMP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol)
- ...